# How to enable alerts/email notifications for only one Site Collection?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, event-receivers

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Background: One Web Application -> Multiple Site Collections -> Multiple Sub-Sites in each Site Collection

I want to implement email/alerts feature only for one Site Collection. I dont want other site collection's users to create alert (or) send email.

After googling a lot, I found *email alerts can be set ON/OFF at Web Application level and not at Site Collection / Site level*.

Is there a way to achieve this by GUI (or) PowerShell Scripts without writing a custom event receiver solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two permissions for alert function:

1. **Create Alerts**: Create alerts.
2. **Manage Alerts**: Manage alerts for all users of the website.

To disable Alert function in site collection level, you can create your custom permission levels and remove Create Alerts permission. Users (except admins) do not have Create Alerts permission cannot create alerts.

Information about [user permissions and permission levels in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: Well, U gave me an idea. Remove 'Create Alerts' permission from all the SharePoint groups under all the Site Collections, except THE ONE. Good idea though, but I have around 200 Site Collection which makes this tedious. Also, Site Collection admin still go in a grant the 'Create Alerts' at any time :(